# can't install pyinstaller with python 3.6 (32)

Tags: installation, python, pip

I tried `pip install pyinstaller`, but keep having error as below, I can't figure out what is wrong even google a lot online. Can someone help?

```
C:\Users\{}\Documents\1Work\PCT\ExcelDiff>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\{}\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe c:\users\{}\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\linlinho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pz5b1j1k\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070D82D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCC10>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCC30>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCE50>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x070DCD30>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

During the `pyinstaller` installation it is trying to download the package `setuptools` because it is a dependency.

Try `pip install setuptools` first.